# Perfexcrm api return 419 status code, how solve it?

Tags: php, api, rest

I use perfexcrm api in my web application.
As its document I pass the URL in postman and also pass authentication token in headers of postman and company name in params in postman.
I try to fetch all customers so I use api/customers as a URL and as a method I use POST for this.
But as a output postman return  status code 419 'Page Expired'.

I also tried pass company name in body tab form-data after that it is return 419 status code.

I shown error in below image

How I solve 419 'Page Expired' error?[image]

As above Image I pass the key and value in body -> form_data

How I solve 419 'Page Expired' error?

Perfexcrm document:https://perfexcrm.themesic.com/apiguide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems CSRF issue.

1. first check in your perfex crm application. CSRF is enable or not. go to

   yoursite.com/admin/settings?group=info
2. if CSRF is enable then disable CSRF. you can disable it from app.config.php

https://prnt.sc/24nf4w1

[image]

Comment: you should NOT disable CSRF, instead add a big number for expiration time `define('APP_CSRF_EXPIRE',3660*24*30);`